# C# Create CheckedComboBoxColumn for DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I found custom ComboBox with checkboxes http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31105/A-ComboBox-with-a-CheckedListBox-as-a-Dropdown and want to use this control in DataGridView cells.

As I understand, need to create custom column class for it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx

I don't understand completely what need to change, try to write similar, but it not work.

```
public class CheckedComboBoxColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public CheckedComboBoxColumn() : base(new CheckedComboBoxCell())
    {
    }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell.
            if (value != null &&
                    !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CheckedComboBoxCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a CheckedComboBoxCell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }

    public class CheckedComboBoxCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    {

        public CheckedComboBoxCell() : base()
        {
        }

        public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object
                                                      initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
        {
            // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.
            base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue,
                                          dataGridViewCellStyle);
            CheckedComboBoxControl ctl =
                DataGridView.EditingControl as CheckedComboBoxControl;

        }

        public override Type EditType
        {
            get
            {
                // Return the type of the editing control that CalendarCell uses.
                return typeof(CheckedComboBoxControl);
            }
        }

        public override Type ValueType
        {
            get
            {
                // Return the type of the value that CalendarCell contains.

                return typeof(CheckedComboBox);
            }
        }

        public override object DefaultNewRowValue
        {
            get
            {
                // Use the current date and time as the default value.
                return new CheckedComboBox();
            }
        }
    }

    public class CheckedComboBoxControl : CheckedComboBox, IDataGridViewEditingControl
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView;
        private bool valueChanged = false;
        int rowIndex;

        public CheckedComboBoxControl()
        {
            //this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue
        // property.
        public object EditingControlFormattedValue
        {
            get
            {
                //return this.Value.ToShortDateString();
                return "";
            }
            set
            {
                if (value is String)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // This will throw an exception of the string is
                        // null, empty, or not in the format of a date.
                        //this.Value = DateTime.Parse((String)value);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        // In the case of an exception, just use the
                        // default value so we're not left with a null
                        // value.
                        //this.Value = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Implements the
        // IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue method.
        public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(
            DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
        {
            return EditingControlFormattedValue;
        }

        // Implements the
        // IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl method.
        public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(
            DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
        {
            this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
            //this.CalendarForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor;
            //this.CalendarMonthBackground = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor;
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex
        // property.
        public int EditingControlRowIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return rowIndex;
            }
            set
            {
                rowIndex = value;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey
        // method.
        public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(
            Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
        {
            // Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed.
            switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
            {
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Home:
            case Keys.End:
            case Keys.PageDown:
            case Keys.PageUp:
                return true;
            default:
                return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit
        // method.
        public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
        {
            // No preparation needs to be done.
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
        // .RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange property.
        public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
        // .EditingControlDataGridView property.
        public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
        {
            get
            {
                return dataGridView;
            }
            set
            {
                dataGridView = value;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
        // .EditingControlValueChanged property.
        public bool EditingControlValueChanged
        {
            get
            {
                return valueChanged;
            }
            set
            {
                valueChanged = value;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
        // .EditingPanelCursor property.
        public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Cursor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try to use like this:

```
DataGridViewRow view_row = dataGridView2.Rows[1];
view_row.Cells[0].Value = "Test";

CheckedComboBox cb = new CheckedComboBox();
cb.MaxDropDownItems = 5;
cb.DisplayMember = "Name";
cb.ValueSeparator = ", ";

foreach (var id_to_user_pair in id_to_user)
{
    cb.Items.Add(new CCBoxItem(id_to_user_pair.Value, id_to_user_pair.Key), true);
}
cb.UpdateText();

view_row.Cells[1].Value = cb;
```

Can you help me?

Comment: did you get success on it? if yes can you please share.  Thanks